# Finding transactions that occurred within 1 minute of each other that also have the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I need to find all transactions that occurred within 1 minute of each other.

An example of output would be something like the following:

```
ID, Transaction_ID  , Datetime
123, 12345          , 2017-02-01 00:01:00 
124, 12345          , 2017-02-01 00:02:00 
125, 12345          , 2017-02-01 02:02:00
```

So, as you can see, the top two transaction ID's are the same, and the transactions were taken within 1 minute of each other so I want display both of those, but not the last as it was taken 2 hours apart even though it has the same transaction ID.

Here is my current query:

```
select t.id, t.datetime, tl.transaction_id
from transactions t
left join transaction_log tl on tl.transaction_log_id = t.id
where t.datetime >= @start
and t.datetime<@end
group by t.id
```

Thank you.

Comment: can explain the logic a little more? what if you have `2:03:00` and  `2:04:00`  ??

Comment: what if there are three transactions within 60 seconds?

Comment: @SalmanA If there are three transctions within 60 seconds then I want to show all of them

Comment: I need to find transactions that were taken within a minute of eachother that also have the same transaction_id. So they could be at a multitude of different times also with several different pairing transaction_id's

Comment: Is the table shown in the question the input or the output? It says output, but then what does the input look like? Why is the last transaction shown if it's not within 1 minute of anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Join the table with itself, using the timestamps in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT t1.transaction_id, t1.id, t1.datetime, t2.id, t2.datetime
FROM transactions AS t1
JOIN transactions AS t2 
    ON t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
    AND t1.datetime >= DATE_SUB(t2.datetime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
    AND t1.id < t2.id
```

Comment: You are adding the second  transactions as column, I think OP want the transactions as rows.

Answer (score 0):

To further Barmar's answer, you will also need to use a group by to filter any duplicate pairs created when there are more than two transactions within the minute.  This is due to the cross join (CROSS JOIN is equivalent to JOIN), which will show every instance of transactions within a minute for each transaction, even itself (i.e: 3 transactions within a minute will have 9 rows total.  The "AND t1.id < t2.id" constraint will reduce this to 3 rows, but not the ones you want.)  A row_number() over (partition by id)=1 could be used, but I don't believe MySQL supports that.

```
SELECT t1.transaction_id, t1.id, t1.datetime, count(*) as cnt
FROM transactions AS t1
CROSS JOIN transactions AS t2 
    ON t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
    AND (t1.datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t2.datetime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD(t2.datetime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE))
    AND t1.id <> t2.id
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

I hope this helps!